# How to get connected tiles in hexagonal grid system

Tags: mathematics, algorithm, path-finding, actionscript-3, hexagonal-grid

I've been developing a game where a number of tiles can drag into a hexagonal grid background.

For some purpose I need to find the location of same tiles into an array and merge them.

Data Layer:

[image]

Presentation Layer:

[image]

I need to find the location of all the tiles those who have same value and connected with each other.

So I need a basic idea, how can I do that or if exists any algorithm.

Note: As3 related code will help.

Comment: I hope this [link](http://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/hex-map-1/) help you

Comment: @smkplus thanks but i don't understand C#.algorithm or sudocode might help

Comment: @moinkhan I'm not sure you tried very hard, just read the C# like it was pseudocode, it's defined with pretty clear variable names.

Answer (score 1):

[Amit's Game Programming Information](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/gameprog.html) extensively covers many different topics, including [hexagonal grids](http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/). It is possibly the best free resource available, and I wholeheartedly recommend it.

For your particular problem, I imagine you would only need to traverse the data structure containing your hex tiles by probing the tiles around your starting tile. You could use a variation of the [flood fill algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) and perform the checks recursively.